# Projecting as USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic_USGS in QGIS?

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-3, united-states

Is it possible to project EPSG: 6350 (NAD83 (2011)) as WKID: 102039 (USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic_USGS) in QGIS?

There is no EPSG code and I'm unsure how to create a custom CRS.

Comment: The parameters for this projection are easily found, so it couldn't hurt to focus this question on converting WKT to GDAL switches, with an initial attempt in the body of the question.

Comment: I think you're right. Also, I think I figured out how to create a custom CRS in QGIS. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

I would use this one ( https://epsg.io/102003):

Look for this in QGIS: **USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic**

According to this link: http://www.hydroterre.psu.edu/HydroTerre/Help/FAQ/FAQ_Projection.aspx , it is the same.

Or: https://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/usa_contiguous_albers_equal_area_conic_usgs_version-2/

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not sure that they are, I thought that the latitude of origin was 37.5 N for the USGS version, but I see a lot of conflicting information regarding this on the internet.

Comment: Can you provide a link a for the conflicting information? I've added another link to my answer, where the parameters are the same like the same...

Comment: Upon more research, it sounds like you are correct. Thanks so much for your help!